# Streaming from a Azure Storage Account

Tags: .net, azure, azure-blob-storage

I have  a .Net Framework 4.7.2 Winforms app I'm
Attempting to Stream a blob from a Azure Storage Account but getting an error "The type initializer for 'PerTypeValues`1'" on .OpenRead() Call. I can upload fine.

```
    Public Function StreamFileFromAzureStorageAcct(ByVal clientLocalFilePath As String, ByVal containerDestName As String, ByRef strReturn As String) As StreamReader

    Dim strReturn As String = String.Empty
    Dim textInStream As Stream = Nothing
    Dim textIn As StreamReader = Nothing
    Dim connectionString As String = Nothing

    Try

        connectionString = String.Format("DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName={0};AccountKey={1};EndpointSuffix={2}", modConfigSettings.AzureStorageAcctName, modConfigSettings.AzureStorageAcctKey, modConfigSettings.AzureStorageAcctURL)
        Dim Container As BlobContainerClient = New BlobContainerClient(connectionString, containerDestName)

        Dim BlobClient As BlobClient = Container.GetBlobClient(Path.GetFileName(clientLocalFilePath))

        Dim readOptions As BlobOpenReadOptions = New BlobOpenReadOptions(False)
        readOptions.Position = 0

        ''Azure Storage Acct Read call returns a Stream
        textInStream = BlobClient.OpenRead(readOptions)

        '' Pass the Stream to a StreamReader to stay inline with existing code.
        textIn = New StreamReader(textInStream)

        strReturn = "Success"

        Return textIn

    Catch er As Exception
        strReturn = String.Format("Failed to Stream from Storage Account: {0}-File:{1}-connectionString: {2}-{3}", er.Message, Path.GetFileName(clientLocalFilePath), connectionString, er.StackTrace)
    End Try

    Return Nothing
End Function
```

> Failed to Stream from Storage Account: The type initializer for 'PerTypeValues`1' threw an exception.- at System.SpanHelpers.IsReferenceOrContainsReferencesT at Azure.Storage.Blobs.BlobRestClient.get_ResponseClassifier200() at Azure.Storage.Blobs.BlobRestClient.CreateGetPropertiesRequest(String snapshot, String versionId, Nullable1 timeout, String leaseId, String
> encryptionKey, String encryptionKeySha256, StringencryptionAlgorithm,String ifTags, RequestConditions requestConditions, RequestContext context) at Azure.Storage.Blobs.BlobRestClient.GetProperties(String snapshot, String versionId, Nullable1 timeout, String leaseId, String encryptionKey, String encryptionKeySha256, String encryptionAlgorithm, String ifTags, RequestConditions requestConditions, RequestContext context) at Azure.Storage.Blobs.Specialized.BlobBaseClient.d__124.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was throw --- at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
> task) atSystem.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task) atAzure.Storage.Blobs.Specialized.BlobBaseClient.d__98.MoveNext() --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown --- atSystem.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task) at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Tasktask) atAzure.Storage.Blobs.Specialized.BlobBaseClient.OpenRead(BlobOpenReadOptions options, CancellationToken cancellationToken) at
> DBAccessObjects.RemFredDataAdmin.StreamFileFromAzureStorageAcct(StringclientLocalFilePath, String containerDestName, String& strReturn) in C:\Users\csale\source\Workspaces\Application Server\FredServer\DBAccessObjects\RemFredDataAdmin.vb:line 15904

Answer (score 0):

*I made some changes to your code and was able to read the content from the blob file.*

***AzureStorageManager.vb***  :

```
Imports Azure.Storage.Blobs
Imports Azure.Storage.Blobs.Models
Imports System.IO

Public Class AzureStorageManager
    Public Function StreamFileFromAzureStorageAcct(ByVal clientLocalPath As String, ByVal containerDestinationName As String, ByRef strReturn As String) As StreamReader
        Dim textInStream As Stream = Nothing
        Dim textIn As StreamReader = Nothing
        Dim connectionString As String = Nothing
        Try
            connectionString = String.Format("<AzureStorageConnectionString>")
            Dim Container As BlobContainerClient = New BlobContainerClient(connectionString, containerDestinationName)
            Dim BlobClient As BlobClient = Container.GetBlobClient(Path.GetFileName(clientLocalPath))
            Dim readOptions As BlobOpenReadOptions = New BlobOpenReadOptions(False)
            readOptions.Position = 0
            textInStream = BlobClient.OpenRead(readOptions)
            textIn = New StreamReader(textInStream)
            strReturn = "Success"
            Return textIn
       Catch er As Exception
         strReturn = String.Format("Failed to Stream from Storage Account: {0}-File:{1}-connectionString: {2}-{3}", er.Message, Path.GetFileName(clientLocalFilePath), connectionString, er.StackTrace)
       End Try
       Return Nothing
    End Function
End Class
```

***Form1.vb***:

```
Imports System.IO

Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim azureManager As New AzureStorageManager()
        Dim filePath As String = "<blobname>" 
        Dim containerName As String = "<containerName>" 
        Dim result As String = "<EmptyString>"
        Dim streamReader As StreamReader = azureManager.StreamFileFromAzureStorageAcct(filePath, containerName, result)
        If streamReader IsNot Nothing Then
            Using streamReader
                Dim content As String = streamReader.ReadToEnd()
                MessageBox.Show("Content read from Azure Storage: " & content)
            End Using
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("Failed to stream file from Azure Storage: " & result)
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

***Output***  :

[image]

***Azure Storage***  :

The content of the blob in the Azure storage is below.

[image]

Comment: I figured out that I had a couple of assemblies with later versions and when I back them down the issue went away.